# update python dictionary values and write result as json output

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a piece of code that loops through a python dictinary, graps the key/values needed and print them in a json format:

my original dictionary looks like this:

```
"mydict": [ 
         {
            "Name": "test", 
            "number": "18", 
            "entity": 0
        }, 
        {
            "Name": "update", 
            "number": "25", 
            "entity": 3
        }, 
        {
            "Name": "manage", 
            "number": "8", 
            "entity": 5
        }
]
```

Here is my code:

```
my_elements = resp.get('mydict')
final= {}
for item in my_elements :
    dic = {item.get('Name') : item.get('number'), 'entity' : item.get('entity')}
    output = json.dumps(dic, indent=4)
    print output
```

This is printing the expected output, however, when I try to write the output I get in a file I only get the last part of the answer and not the whole dictionary, this is what I get:

```
{
    "manage": 8,
    "entity": 5
}
```

while I want to get:

```
{
    "test": 18,
    "entity": 0
}
{
    "update": 25,
    "entity": 3
}
{
    "manage": 8,
    "entity": 5
}
```

This is the code I added hoping to get the needed output:

```
with open ('result.json','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(dic, outfile,)
```

But this returns the first output I do not desire. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the dictionary to a list and then dump the list to a json file

**Ex:**

```
my_elements = resp.get('mydict')
final= []
for item in my_elements :
    final.append({item.get('Name') : item.get('number'), 'entity' : item.get('entity')})

with open ('result.json','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(final, outfile)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting the last part of the answer only.

Comment: have you tried exactly as above with the correct indentation?

Comment: Sorry, it is actually working, as my code is originally more complex and has a loop within a loop, was able to get it to work now using your code. Thanks.